# Is it possible to add a column to an existing clustered index in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to know if it is possible to add a column to an existing clustered index on a table in sql server 2008? If so, is it possible to do it online?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the definition of the clustered index (ie. add a new column to the keys) as an online operation. I don't have an instance to validate, but the syntax is something like following:

```
create clustered index [indexname] on [table]([column], [column], [column], ...)
with (drop_existing =on, online = on);
```

The operation is fully online (table is open for reads, inserts, updates and deletes). You need an Enterprise Edition instance (because only EE supports online index build operations) and the table cannot have LOB columns (at least up to [SQL Server 2012 it cannot](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/05/online-index-operations-for-indexes-containing-lob-columns/)).

The operation is a full rebuild of the table, heavy in resources and will generate significant log.

Comment: when the rebuild happens, the queries would do a table scan or use the old one till the new one gets built and drop the old one after that?

Comment: [How Online Operations Work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191261.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a column to an existing index but you can drop the index and re-create it with the additional column.

You can do it online, but it could be a heavy and time-consuming operation if the table is big.

Comment: how can you drop the index and build it online?

Comment: @SriramSubramanian SQL Server Enterprise edition (2008 and 2008 R2 - not sure about 2005) allow for online rebuilding of indexes... but I don't recall how clustered indexes figure into online index rebuilding

Comment: If you rebuild a clustered index, all non-clustered indexes will be re-created as well, as they use the clustered index as part of their key